# How to figure out the free body diagram?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

> This was the part of the Motivation to the definition of **Green's Function**. I am referring this problem from the book *Ordinary Differential Equations* by *Tyn Myint-U.* I am not able to figure out the Free body diagram of the problem. Please help me to derive the equation in the red box. I have no idea how the author figure out the equation in the box. Author didn't include any diagram. So, it creates confusion to a reader.

**My attempt to figure out the Free body diagram:**

[image]

Comment: The tension will not be constant..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical components of forces acting on the portion of string between $x$ and $x + dx$ are:

1. At $x$, it is $T(x) \sin(\theta (x))$ upwards.
2. At $x+dx$, it is $T(x+dx) \sin(\theta (x + dx))$ upwards.
3. $\rho(x) g \space dx $ gravity, downwards.

The horizontal components are:

1. $T(x) \cos(\theta (x))$ towards left.
2. $T(x+dx) \cos(\theta (x + dx))$ towards right.

Both horizontal and vertical components add up to zero, since the string is at rest.

**Horizontal components**: $T(x) \cos(\theta (x)) = T(x+dx) \cos(\theta (x + dx))$. If the *string has little bend*, then we can allow $$ T(x + dx) \approx T(x) = T(x)$$ (and $\cos(\theta (x)) \approx \cos(\theta (x + dx))$).

**Vertical components**: $$T(x) \sin(\theta (x)) + T(x+dx) \sin(\theta (x + dx)) -\rho(x) g dx = 0 $$ With the approximation $T(x +dx) \approx T(x) = T(x)$,
$$T(x) \left[\sin(\theta (x)) + \sin(\theta (x + dx)) \right] = \rho(x) g dx$$

**Approximations:**
Again by our assumption that *the string has little bend*, angles $\theta(x)$ and $\theta(x+dx)$ can be considered *small*, so that the *sines* can be approximated by the *tan*'s:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sin(\theta(x)) &\approx \tan(\theta(x)) \\ 
\sin(\theta(x+dx)) &\approx \tan(\theta(x+dx))
\end{split}
\end{equation}

and finally, the *tan's* can be related to the slopes of the string at $x$ and $x+dx$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\tan(\theta(x)) &= - y'(x) \\
\tan(\theta(x+dx) &= y'(x+dx)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

So,
\begin{equation}
T(x) \left[\sin(\theta (x)) + \sin(\theta (x + dx)) \right] = \rho(x) g dx \implies T(x) [-y'(x) + y'(x+dx)] = \rho(x) g dx
\end{equation}

Dividing both sides by $dx$,

\begin{equation}
\frac{y'(x+dx) - y'(x)}{dx} = \frac{\rho g}{T(x)} \implies \boxed{
\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = \frac{\rho g}{T(x)}
}
\end{equation}

[[image: Forces on segment of string between <span class=]$x$ and $x+dx$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UBh3.png)

Comment: Bit long, but boils down to the free body diagram of an infinitesimal portion of the string, and making assumptions on the way.

Comment: Hello, But Author didn't tell about whether bending is small or large. I like your derivation. Can you clarify this?

Comment: Also g is not given in the equation.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by vertical reaction?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/685463/

Comment: Can you help me with this question also?

Comment: This question is related to this question.

Comment: 1. Author didn't show the derivation of this equation. He started using it without any justification, in order to show the rest that follows.

Comment: $g$ has to be present, according to Newton's second law, the force due to gravity is $F = ma$, for a particle being pulled down by gravity, $a = g \implies F = mg$.

Comment: Without the assumption that *the bend is small*, the equation would become more complicated. *sines* have to be expressed in terms of *y'*, which won't give a simple equation as the one above.

Comment: Also I do not know what $a_1$ and $b_1$ represent, so I cannot say more. I should know what is before than what is shown in the picture.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/685463/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132651/discussion-between-unknown-x-and-anu3082).